# RegEx - True if not in list

Tags: regex

I would like a regEx to return true if a string is not an exact match to a list of other strings.  There may be better ways to do this than with RegEx, but for my purposes, I need to use a regex method for validation.

For example, the list contains

```
aaa aab aac dvs efg
```

I want the expression to match, if I type for example:

```
aa 
a
aae
```

But I want it to fail on an exact match like the values
  aaa
  aab

I tried something like:

```
[^aaa|aab|aac|dvs|efg]
```

But that's not working, it finds that 'aa', 'aaa', 'aab' (for example) are all not matches.
I don't want 'aa' to not be a match.
aa should match because it's not identically equal to one of the strings in the list.

Comment: What are your reasons for needing a regex? What language is this?

Comment: Vertical bar `|` inside of a character class `[...]` means vertical bar, not OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using is to get a character that does that match the characters specified.

What you are looking for is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

It could be used like this:

```
^(?:(?!^(aaa|aab|aac|dvs|efg)$).)*$
```

Also, as others have mentioned always make sure you really NEED to use RegEx (hard to understand why you would be forced to use a specific technology other than homework).

Here is an example of this problem in C#:

[Version using built in `Collection` methods](http://ideone.com/URH7qK) takes 1.59 s with 1 unique, understandable line of code.

[Version using RegEx](http://ideone.com/c1bIys) takes 4.55 s with 3 unique, more complex lines of code.

Comment: @GeorgeHernando: OP wrote: `if a string is not an exact match to a list of other strings`. will this work for input: `"aaab"` which is not in OP's list?

Comment: @anubhava no, you are correct, I misread to question. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work for you:

```
^(?!\b(?:aaa|aab|aac|dvs|efg)\b).*$
```

**Explanation:** Match a string that is not exactly in the list of the given strings using negative lookahead.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/BMuCk5S6PJ